# Get the Generic Type in Dependency Injection Asp Net Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I Want to archive a global solution to all of my generic services, I Have the following code:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), provider => ResolveService(genericType));
```

I need one parameter that is the generic type needed to resolve the service and return the right instance.

There is a way to extract the Generic type needed by the interface in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use service resolver in your classes then. But you should know - this is an [*anti-pattern*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

```
public interface IService<T>
    {

    }

    public interface IResolveService
    {
        IService<T> Resolve<T>();
    }

    public class ResolveService : IResolveService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

        public ResolveService(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public IService<T> Resolve<T>()
        {
            //some logic here. May by resolving some instances using IServiceProvider
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(IResolveService resolveService)
        {
            Service = resolveService.Resolve<int>();
        }

        private IService<int> Service { get; }
    }
```

Comment: I think I'd have to implement a different technique to archive this.

Comment: please, write the answer if u will)

Comment: No, just for my purpose I've to change this injection by another general purpose solution, like create a generic class and by constructor resolve the behaviour of the class based on the generic type.